# Libreoffice 6.4 Calc uses only one CPU core, and most computers have now from 8 to 32 of them. In a 200,000 rows spreadsheet anything takes minutes

Tags: libreoffice-calc

My computer based on a `i7-3820` goes at the same speed than a `286 PC/AT` in a spreadsheet of 220,000 lines, when using *LibreOffice Calc 6.4* :

- Centering a column that holds lines of two characters content : 4 minutes.
- Formatting a number column : 3 minutes.
- Opening the `.ods` of 55 MB takes more than ten minutes.

I found why : *Libreoffice 6.4* **is using only one CPU core** of my computer (at 100%, I have to say it) and not up to the eight it has.

Is there any way to change its behavior and support computers of today ?

Comment: Just checkiing (although you have not mentioned calculations), is Tools->Options-> LbreOffice Calc->Calculate-> "Enable multi-threaded calculation" enabled?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Good idea. I didn't know. But it was checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LibreOffice Calc is not yet multi-threaded, so uses only one core.

This is discussed in the
[Bug 65046 : Threaded calculation of formula groups (multi-threading)](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65046),
dating from 2013 (!).

In 2018, this was described as "work-in-process" (comment #16).

In December 2019 this bug report received a High priority because
"the number of duplicates is higher than 5 or the number of people in CC higher than 20",
meaning that this problem appeared also in multiple other bug reports.

At the moment this feature seems still not implemented
([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243090/why-is-libreoffice-using-only-one-core)).

As converting a program such as Calc to be multi-threaded is a huge task,
I don't expect this to be available any time soon.

Comment: That's the problem of Opensource : developers loves creating new features, but it's hard to see them agreeing to solve defectives ones. It might take months sometimes to convince them to correct a bug they left somewhere.